# shortcuts in append function in python

Tags: python, numpy, append

I am programming newbie here, so sorry for these elementary questions.
I am dealing with python code which has vectors and a lot of append function. For example lines like these

```
a = [[],[],[]]
a[0].append(1)
a[1].append(2)
a[2].append(5)
```

So I was wondering if the above lines could be rewritten as a shorter code. Since this is a vector I guess numpy arrays could be useful here. But i have heard that append function does not goes well with numpy. I would appreciate any help on this.

Regards.

Comment: Though if you use the term "vector" you will be understood, in Python, those are called "lists".

Comment: no that was just a example, it has a lot of loops with append. So i was wondering if those three append lines could be written as a single append line or something. That will make the code much neater.

Comment: I removed my comment. I realized your case was more general.

Comment: basically i am interested in combining those last three lines to a single line if that would be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the most pythonic way I can think of to create and then append to the list of lists. Best for Python 3 where `zip` is a generator function.

```
a = [[] for i in range(0,3)]
for i,j in zip(a,[1,2,5]):
    i.append(j)
```

For python 2, `zip` will allocate a lot of memory if lists are huge, so prefer the more classic:

```
a = [[] for i in range(0,3)]
b=[1,2,5]
for i,l in enumerate(a):
    l.append(b[i])
```

Comment: thise numbers are not in a nice sequence unfortunately. Sorry i guess i gave a bad example here

Comment: changed my answer.